# Using ng-options with a nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json array formatted like this:

```
share.videos = [
  {
    sources: [
      {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/Inner_Strength.mp4'), type: 'video/mp4'},
      {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/Inner_Strength.webm'), type: 'video/webm'},
      {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/Inner_Strength.ogv'), type: 'video/ogg'}
    ],
    info: [
      {
        'title': 'Inner Strength',
        'videoFile': 'Inner_Strength_HD.mp4'
      }
    ]
  }]
```

I would like to use ng-options to get the title from info.title

```
ng-options="i.info.title for i in share.videos"
```

Gives me blank labels in my select element on my DOM, but with the right amount of options.

Is it possible to use ng-options with an array formatted like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info` is an array not object.

You have to specify it's index.

Try like this

```
ng-options="i.info[0].title for i in share.videos"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
ng-options="video in share.videos"
    ng-options="inf in video.info"
        {{inf.title}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `info` has multiple titles like below -

```
share.videos = [
  {
    sources: [
      {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/Inner_Strength.mp4'), type: 'video/mp4'},
      {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/Inner_Strength.webm'), type: 'video/webm'},
      {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/Inner_Strength.ogv'), type: 'video/ogg'}
    ],
    info: [
      {
        'title': 'Inner Strength',
        'videoFile': 'Inner_Strength_HD.mp4'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Another Title',
        'videoFile': 'Inner_Strength_HD_another.mp4'
      },

    ]
  }]
```

In this case, you should use it like -

```
ng-options="i.title for i in share.videos[0].info"
```